# Creating a csv file using scrapy

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, scrapy

I've created a script using Python in association with Scrapy to parse the movie names and its years spread across multiple pages from a torrent site. My goal here is to write the parsed data in a CSV file other than using the built-in command provided by Scrapy, because when I do this:

```
scrapy crawl  torrentdata -o outputfile.csv -t csv
```

I get a blank line in every alternate row in the CSV file.

However, I thought to go in a slightly different way to achieve the same thing. Now, I get a data-laden CSV file in the right format when I run the following script. Most importantly I made use of a `with statement` while creating a CSV file so that when the writing is done the file gets automatically closed. I used `crawlerprocess` to execute the script from within an IDE.

> My question: Isn't it a better idea for me to follow the way I tried below?

This is the working script:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import csv

class TorrentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "torrentdata"
    start_urls = ["https://yts.am/browse-movies?page={}".format(page) for page in range(2,20)] #get something within list
    itemlist = []

    def parse(self, response):
        for record in response.css('.browse-movie-bottom'):
            items = {}
            items["Name"] = record.css('.browse-movie-title::text').extract_first(default='')
            items["Year"] = record.css('.browse-movie-year::text').extract_first(default='')
            self.itemlist.append(items)

        with open("outputfile.csv","w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f,['Name','Year'])
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in self.itemlist:
                writer.writerow(data)

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',   
})
c.crawl(TorrentSpider)
c.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

By putting the CSV exporting logic into the spider itself, you are re-inventing the wheel and not using all the advantages of Scrapy and its components and, also, making the crawling slower as you are writing to disk in the crawling stage every time the callback is triggered.

As you mentioned, the *CSV exporter is built-in*, you just need to yield/return items from the `parse()` callback:

```
import scrapy


class TorrentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "torrentdata"
    start_urls = ["https://yts.am/browse-movies?page={}".format(page) for page in range(2,20)] #get something within list

    def parse(self, response):
        for record in response.css('.browse-movie-bottom'):
            yield {
                "Name": record.css('.browse-movie-title::text').extract_first(default=''),
                "Year": record.css('.browse-movie-year::text').extract_first(default='')
            }
```

Then, by running:

```
scrapy runspider spider.py -o outputfile.csv -t csv
```

(or the `crawl` command)

you would have the following in the `outputfile.csv`:

```
Name,Year
"Faith, Love & Chocolate",2018
Bennett's Song,2018
...
Tender Mercies,1983
You Might Be the Killer,2018
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I'm not an expert on this, I thought to come up with a solution which I've been following quite some time.
Making use of `signals` might be a wise attempt here. When the scraping process is done, the `spider_closed()` method is invoked and thus the `DictWriter()` will be open once and when the writing is finished, it will be closed automatically because of the `with statement`. That said there is hardly any chance for your script to be slower, if you can get rid of `Disk I/O` issues.

The following script represents what I told you so far:

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy import signals
import csv

class TorrentSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "torrentdata"
    start_urls = ["https://yts.am/browse-movies?page={}".format(page) for page in range(2,10)] #get something within list
    itemlist = []

    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        spider = super().from_crawler(crawler)
        crawler.signals.connect(spider.spider_closed, signals.spider_closed)
        return spider

    def spider_closed(self):
        with open("outputfile.csv","w", newline="") as f:
            writer = csv.DictWriter(f,['Name','Year'])
            writer.writeheader()
            for data in self.itemlist:
                writer.writerow(data)

    def parse(self, response):
        for record in response.css('.browse-movie-bottom'):
            items = {}
            items["Name"] = record.css('.browse-movie-title::text').extract_first(default='')
            items["Year"] = record.css('.browse-movie-year::text').extract_first(default='')
            self.itemlist.append(items)

c = CrawlerProcess({
    'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0',   
})
c.crawl(TorrentSpider)
c.start()
```